# Chef recipe 'include_recipe' takes precedence over other code and resources

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm attempting to create a Chef cookbook that, for now, is mostly just a wrapper cookbook for another cookbook (the [audit cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/audit)). I'm still learning Chef, but from what I can gather from the [About Recipes documentation](https://docs.chef.io/recipes.html#include-recipes) and the [Resources Reference documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_reference.html#id96), Chef recipes should execute in the order that they're defined (via Ruby code and/or Chef resources).

In the About Recipes documentation, it mentions that

> When a recipe is included, the resources found in that recipe will be
>   inserted (in the same exact order) at the point where the
>   include_recipe keyword is located.

In the Resources Reference documentation, they have an **apt_update** resource that presumably executes before the **include_recipe** method due to the fact that it's defined earlier in the recipe.

My wrapper cookbook has a single recipe, default.rb, which is literally these two lines:

```
package 'ruby-dev'
include_recipe 'audit'
```

However, during a chef-client or chef-solo run I see that the *audit::inspec* recipe runs before the *security::default* recipe which causes things to break because InSpec has some other dependencies that need to be installed beforehand. Before I used the **package** resource I was using the **execute** resource to explicitly run `apt-get install ruby-dev` or `yum install ruby-dev` depending on the platform using a case statement, but same problem (all that code was skipped and the **include_recipe** method called first).

In case it's useful, I'm using Chef 12 which I realize is EOL but I have other dependencies that require me to stick with this version of Chef for now.

I may very well just be misunderstanding how Chef converges work and the order in which execution occurs, but it's causing me a lot of grief so I'd really appreciate some pointers! Does **include_recipe** always occur before other code within your recipe? Is there any way around this? Am I missing something?

**-- EDIT --**

I was able to get the desired functionality (install other packages and gems before an `include_recipe` call triggered installation of a dependency gem) using the following code in my cookbook recipe:

```
package 'build-essential' do
  action :nothing
end.run_action(:install)

chef_gem 'train' do
  version "1.4.4"
  action :install
end

chef_gem 'signet' do
  version "0.11.0"
  action :install
end

include_recipe 'audit'
```

Note that I ended up installing the `build-essential` package rather than the `ruby-dev` package from my original code snippet, and also installed two gems for Chef client to use. This all gets installed in the order I expected during the compile phase of the Chef run.

Sources:

- https://docs.chef.io/resource_reference.html#run-in-compile-phase
- https://docs.chef.io/resource_chef_gem.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you would examine the `audit::inspec` rescipe, you will find that it uses a compile time [installation of the inspec rubygem](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/audit/blob/master/recipes/inspec.rb#L24) (see the last line)

```rb
inspec_gem 'inspec' do
  version node['audit']['inspec_version']
  source node['audit']['inspec_gem_source']
  action :nothing
end.run_action(:install)
```

from [chef documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#run-action):

> **run_action**
>
> Use `.run_action(:some_action)` at the end of a resource block to run the specified action during the compile phase.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I had to do a little reading on "compile phase" vs. "execution phase" as outlined in https://docs.chef.io/chef_client_overview.html#the-chef-infra-client-run but that makes more sense now.

I've updated my question to contain code I was able to use to achieve the desired behavior.